# Trigger Javascript events only on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, hammer.js

I'm trying to trigger some JS events only on touch (for showing or not a side menu on a responsive project). I've looked at Hammer.js, followed the basics and here is what I come of with :

```
var $mainPage = $('#main-page');
  var drawer = 0;
  $mainPage.hammer()
                .on('swiperight', function(e){
                  if(drawer){
                    return true;
                  }
                  $mainPage.css({'transform': 'translateX(260px)', '-ms-transform': 'translateX(260px)', '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(260px)'});
                  drawer = 1;
                })
                .on('swipeleft', function(e){
                  if(!drawer){
                    return true;
                  }
                  $mainPage.css({'transform': 'translateX(0)', '-ms-transform': 'translateX(0)', '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(0)'});
                  drawer = 0;
                });
```

Everything seems to be fine except it's not only triggering on touch event but with mouse events too. If I try to reproduce the swype with my mouse, it works too... And I don't like it :)

So, I was wondering how I could do it, only firing events only on touch actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hammer.js will always work with mouse events. Ideally I try to detect touch with Modernizr or using JavaScript and then initialize hammer code.

```
if (Modernizr.touch) { 
    //your hammer code
}
```

OR using plain javascript.

```
var supportsTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

if(supportsTouch){
  // your hammer code
}
```